# getting error trying to create log4j2 rollingfileappender

Tags: java, configuration, rollingfileappender, log4j2

I'm trying to switch from using FileAppender to the RollingFileAppender using log4j2 (happens both with beta3 and beta4 jars).

I have it configured as:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${logdir}/${filename}" 
    filePattern="${logdir}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss}_%i.log" >
    <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
</RollingFile>  
        ...
<loggers>
          <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
        ...
```

and in the code, I'm trying to get the logger this way:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

but I'm getting this exception when I run it:

```
2013-02-01 17:56:54,773 ERROR Unable to invoke method createAppender in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration.createPluginObject(BaseConfiguration.java:723)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration.createConfiguration(BaseConfiguration.java:489)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration.createConfiguration(BaseConfiguration.java:481)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration.doConfigure(BaseConfiguration.java:162)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.BaseConfiguration.start(BaseConfiguration.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:271)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:287)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:139)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:31)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:342)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:301)
         ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:140)
    ... 18 more
```

It looks as if the config file is being read and the appender is trying to get created but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried cutting and pasting other people's RollingFileAppender configuration w/o any modification but I still get the above error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

In my case configuration file contain `File appender` with `RollingFile appender`.

> Error was in `fileName` parameter - it have same value in both
>   appenders.

Comment: This seems correct.  Apparently (as of 2.3) you cannot have two different `Appenders` with the same `fileName`